# How to modify built-in types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, built-in-types

I am stuck in a scenario where I want to modify a global type. Trying to change the signature of the `Element.prototype.animate` (want to make it optional) function.

Tried something like this

```
declare global {
  interface Element {
    animate?: Animatable['animate'];
  }
}
```

However, it causes the following TS error:

```sh
Interface 'Element' incorrectly extends interface 'Animatable'.  
  Types of property 'animate' are incompatible.
    Type '((keyframes: PropertyIndexedKeyframes | Keyframe[] | null, options?: number | KeyframeAnimationOptions | undefined) => Animation) | undefined' is not assignable to type '(keyframes: PropertyIndexedKeyframes | Keyframe[] | null, options?: number | KeyframeAnimationOptions | undefined) => Animation'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(keyframes: PropertyIndexedKeyframes | Keyframe[] | null, options?: number | KeyframeAnimationOptions | undefined) => Animation'.
```

How can this be solved without turning off any kind of TS checks?

Comment: But `animate` exists on *every* native `Element` - what code are you writing that needs it to be optional?

Answer (score -1):

Will this work for you...

```
type OptionalAnimate = Omit<Element, "animate"> & {
    animate?: Animatable['animate'];
}
```